# NavigationBarTitle Text Color in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar

I'm trying to change my navigationBarTitle Color (not background). I tried a couple solution but my title text color only changes when I scroll down. Not changing when screen open.

[image]

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack{
    NavigationView{
      ScrollView{
        LazyVStack{
          ForEach(storeArray,id:\.id) { item in
            Image(uiImage: (item.banner?.url)!.load())
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9), height: CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio) ?? 1))))
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .shadow(radius: 4)
                .aspectRatio(CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio)!), contentMode: .fit)
          }
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("United App").foregroundColor(.blue))
      .background (NavigationConfigurator { nc in
          nc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue]
      })
    }
    .onAppear {
        if isOpened != true {
            getStoreResponse()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the same for large title

```
.background (NavigationConfigurator { nc in
    
    nc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue]
    nc.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue]
    
})
```

the alternate is to use appearance instead of configurator, but it should be done in `init` of view (before `NavigationView` created) like

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I didnt know that largetitle represent different text .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a more complete approach:

```
    init() {
        let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

            // for inline displayMode
            coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
            
            // for automatic and large displayMode
            coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
            
            // or
            
            // for inline displayMode
    //        coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.font:UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
            // for automatic and large displayMode
    //        coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font:UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

            // to make everything work normally
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Screnn")
                .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        // Do not forget this
        // that means only show one view at a time no matter what device I'm working
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Call this in initialize

```
init() {
    setNavigationAppearance()
   }
```

Use this function to change navigation bar title and background color in swiftUI

```
 func setNavigationAppearance() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    
    let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
      .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBackground,
      .font: UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 56, weight: .black)
    ]
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = attrs
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**